# How to use session$userData correctly in Shiny

Tags: r, session, shiny

What is the correct way of getting/setting values in `session$userData` for Shiny applications? [The documentation states](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/session.html):

> userData: An environment for app authors and module/package authors to store whatever session-specific data they want.

And is `userData` only available when executing in apps on the Shiny server after the user has logged in?

I tried to work with `session$userData` while running an app from within RStudio IDE, but `session$userData` is `NULL`, and I get errors saying "cannot add bindings to a locked environment".

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage()

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Returns NULL 
  print(session$userData)

  # will throw an error
  session$userData$test <- "test value"
  attr(session$userData,"test") <- "test value" 

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Possibly related:**

- https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/1513
- https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1512

Comment: I tested with Shiny version 1.0.3 and seems that it's working. What version do you have?

Comment: @Geovany: Thanks, I was using an old version of the Shiny package that simply did not yet have that functionality. Now the above works perfectly.